# Click button from main view controller to save recorded video in container view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uiimagepickercontroller

My app records video, does playback and saves the video. I use container views inside a main view controller. Like the UISegmentedControl in the main view controller, my (SaveVideo)button is out of the container view. Therefore, I'm unable to save the recorded video.

My code as follows in ViewController.m:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
   if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
    // Saving the video / // Get the new unique filename
    sourcePath = [[info  objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]relativePath];
}
  [self.videoController play];
}   


- (IBAction)saveVideo:(id)sender
{
  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);   
}
```

I'm getting this following error in console:

```
'[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

What can I do so that the **button in my main view controller recognizes the sourcePath of recorded video in the container view** ?

Answer (score 2):

Keep a reference to the container view controller in your main view controller.

```
@interface mainViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) containerViewController;
@end
```

Then in your containerViewController keep a property in your header file referencing your source path.

```
//containerViewController.h
@interface containerViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sourcePath;
@end
```

Then when the save video button is selected you can reference your containerViewController source path property.

```
- (IBAction)saveVideo:(id)sender
{
  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.containerViewController.sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);   
}
```

Comment: Very helpful but I'm getting an error. 
What's the **object type** of 'containerViewController' ?

Comment: The container view controller will be a subclass of UIViewController. It is  the same "view controller" as your "container views", but I didn't know the name of your'd given it. If you're still having trouble, I'd upload more code showing how you represent your container views and transition to them.